# Newby question. Converged sequence ? Demonstration

Tags: sequences-and-series

Good day to all,

Today, I was wondering how to demonstrate that the following sequence converged:

$\left\lbrace \dfrac{\left( n!\right) ^c }{\left( 3n \right) ! } \right\rbrace _{n=0}^{n=\infty}, c> 3 $

or, please, can somebody suggest me a book?

**extra info, I'm chemist not mathematician**

Comment: Is this a series (summation of terms) or a sequence?

Comment: Do you want to show that the sequence converges? Or that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n!)^c}{(3n)!}$ converges?

Comment: yes it is, I'm going to up the math expression

Comment: @jameselmore and graydad is a sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\text{If }a_n = \frac{(n!)^c}{(3n)!}\text{, consider }\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n!)^c}{((n+1)!)^c}\frac{(3n+3)!}{(3n)!}=\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(n+1)^c}$$

Any thoughts on how this might behave as $n\to\infty?$

---

EDIT:
Taking what we have above about $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$,
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(n+1)^c}\leq\frac{3^3(n+1)^3}{(n+1)^c}=3^3(n+1)^{3-c}$$
$$\text{We've reduced the problem to: }\lim_{n\to\infty}3^3(n+1)^{3-c}$$
You gave a key piece of information earlier, "$c>3$", knowing this our problem is complete.

Comment: nope, in fact, this is my first approach to this math field

Comment: very silly question, why is the limit taken?

Comment: Which limit, the one you propose, or the limit of the ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$?

Comment: the limit of the ratio

Comment: This is a common test for convergence. If we can show that the limit of this ratio, $L$, is $<1$, this means that our sequence decreases to $0$. If this ratio is $>1$ it means it does not converge. If the ratio $=1$, we can't make any conclusions from this test, and need to find another method

Comment: Thank so much for the explanation, now I know a way to propouse a sequence demostration and some references to analyzed its convergence or divergence. But, I have another two silly questions: i.) why or based on what the factorial is eliminated and how appeared: $\frac{3^3(n+1)^3}{(n+1)^c}=3^3(n+1)^{3-c}$ ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hints:   
 
$\frac{(n+1)!}{n!} = \frac{(n+1)(n)(n-1)...2\cdot 1}{(n)(n-1)...2\cdot 1} = ...\text{, think about what terms may cancel.}$  
$(a^n/a^m) = a^n\cdot a^{-m} = a^{n-m}$